# How can I increase the volume on my Asus laptop?

Tags: audio, speakers, asus-laptop

Even with the volume all the way to "11", the volume on my Asus laptop is often not loud enough. How can I increase the volume?

Comment: The Chrome volume suddenly became low (May 2020) on my Asus laptop, so went to Settings> Sound > "App Volume and Device Preferences" and found my Google Chrome Volume to be at 20/100. Turned it up and was fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Control Panel

Select Hardware and Sound > Manage Audio Devices > Speakers > Properties > Enhancements, check "Loudness Equalization"

Comment: If you are using media player classic, you may also tweak at the option > Internal filters > audio switcher : increase Boost, or adjust normalize, or both.  || to crank up more of the any media file.

Comment: @p._phidot_: Where does one first get to "Internal filters"?

Comment: The "media player classic" I've mention refers to is [mpc-hc](https://mpc-hc.org/) aka "Media Player Classic - Home Cinema".

Comment: @p._phidot_: All down but nine; set 'em up on the other alley, pard. IOW, how would I get to this "mpc-hc"?

Comment: you may download it at its website : https://mpc-hc.org/ ( :

Comment: Now it's "Hardware and Sound" > "Manage Audio Devices" etc.

Comment: sorry, is that a new option.. or a new question .. /(^_^)

Comment: It's the new way of doing it. That's why it starts, "Now it's..."

Comment: okay.. got it.. An updated answer. Great!

Answer (score 6):

I just bought an ASUS Notebook in July 2019.  The sound was horrible!!!  I could barely hear most of the youtube videos.

I stumbled on the realtek audio console when plugging in my headphone jack as a popup menu.

Later, I found the actual program or App, in the windows drop down menu.

Once you find it Realtek Audio Console, there will be two options for adjusting the settings for Microphone and Speakers.

I clicked on the settings tab for Speakers and found all of the Equalizer Settings for the speakers.

I started a youtube video in the background and went back to the Equalizer while the video was playing and adjusted the settings to my desired levels.

I increased the sound by close to double what it was when I got the computer!!!  Huge difference!!!

Hope this helps.

Comment: there is no equalizer in my  Realtek Audio Console :(

Answer (score 5):

Tl;dr: delete Audio Wizard.

Some ASUS machines come with a software called Audio Wizard. (When you plug in a pair of headphones or a speaker, smart audio will pop up automatically, and in the bottom right corner you'll see the icon and something like "open audio wizard"). It allows you to mess around with the sound and has several settings such as "music" "movie" etc. DELETE THIS PROGRAM. After deleting this, the volume on my laptop became significantly louder. I think it was just dampening certain frequencies for effect.

I found out how to solve this problem on my own 2019 laptop and couldn't find it anywhere else on the internet, so although this was posted two years ago, I am leaving it here for posterity.

Answer (score 4):

My Asus ROG laptop suddenly started having a similar audio problem: Audio such as Youtube or podcasts would start out loud, then after a few seconds would self adjust to a level about 20-30% lower (so even at full volume it was low).

After reading answers here, and trying some of them, what worked for me was:

Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound move to Communications tab, click the "Do Nothing" radio button (it was set to "Reduce the volume by 80%").

I'm on Windows 8.1 so this may be located elsewhere on Windows 10.

Comment: There is that option on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

*I actually have an Asus Vivobook myself and the sound is actually pretty low to be honest so it could be normal yet annoying.*

But to be safe make sure all s**ound-related drivers are correctly installed and up-to-date**. *Sound may be low but it should definitely be audible*.

If drivers are OK, check if some installed sound drivers offer you **customization** of some kind (different than windows parameters) where you could maybe increase the volume. 
Not possible on my Asus but it was an option on my previous laptop (MSI) so it's worth checking.

As mentioned in an answer, make sure that the **Windows (or other OS) parameters** on Sound/Speakers are set to maximum.

If at this point you still want to increase the volume it is possible to some extent but it will very likely result in some quality decrease. 
You can install **third-party software** designed to increase the volume such as Letasoft Sound Booster or DFX Audio Enhancer. You can surely find quite a lot of them online with a quick search, I don't have any personal recommendations.

For an incomplete workaround, lots of software differ in how they manage sound and volume and may allow for much "louder" sound delivery. For instance VLC Media Player will allow you to set the volume higher than Windows Media Player, same with MusicBee versus Itunes, etc. But this is OK for specific uses only of course.

Answer (score 2):

I bought Asus Vivobook in September 2019 and found the audio loudness to be very low. After some searching I found the culprit to **Audio Wizard**. But **you need not uninstall it.**

Rather open the advanced settings menu in the software and then open the equalizer settings. There simply increase the gain of the various frequencies and and the filter settings to one which suits you the best.I found that changing the **peaking** option to **high shelving** almost doubles the loudness !
[Here is the screenshot of the settings I applied.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPE7e.jpg)