# Volume issues on an Asus laptop

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, asus-laptop, telegram-messenger, web-whatsapp

So Win 8.1 did an update yesterday and all of a sudden my old Asus laptop wouldn't boot into Windows (it was stuck on the Asus screen) & I figured out it was the USB hub and I could only boot into Windows when the hub was unplugged.

Then when using my headphone to send voice messages on Telegram & Skype I couldn't hear hardly anything even though the other person could me fine. Very low volume.

We uninstalled the 2 possible pieces of Windows malware and BAMM, my USB hub works now on restart.

Unfortunately I still can't hear any voice messages in Telegram and now on WhatsApp for browser. Skype seems to be fine now. And all settings tests like in Skype, the windows volume test area are fine & I can hear VLC fine thru the headset.

We tried everything in this thread (I am using an old Asus laptop) & now after doing comment 4, I can't even get my volume to go up or down when I move it. And that's even after putting the setting back to default. [How can I increase the volume on my Asus laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/1256674/how-can-i-increase-the-volume-on-my-asus-laptop)

Before at least that was working. sigh

I really need to hear things via my headset when I listen to & leave VMs on TG, WhatsApp, etc. And also, my external speakers work FINE. Can someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but if you had malware, you should seriously consider a fresh install of Windows. Also, since you are on 8.1 which reaches EOL (End of Life) for security patches tomorrow (1/10/23) it is time to bite the bullet and install a fresh Windows 11 installation (or 10 if you prefer).

It sounds to me like the issue is now, after your fixes, only with the browser, but you also say your external speakers work, but just not your headphones. If that's true and assuming the headphones and speakers plug into the same audio out port, it's likely your headphones have failed in some way. You'll need to try another set of headphones to rule that out.

Anyway, since you've found malware on your PC, you really should reinstall the OS from scratch and since your OS is end of life, you should install a new one.

Sorry if that's not very helpful, but with so many variables and changes you've mentioned it's hard to nail anything down to one likely cause.

Comment: Incase you are dead set on not installing a new OS, I recommend these steps to verify and fix any corruption with your Windows installation. I'm not 100% sure this will work once your OS hits EOL tomorrow since it uses Windows Update services to verify and fix/replace invalid libraries...there is a way to do this offline, but it's a bit more complicated and requires downloading and mounting a Windows installation image.

https://howtofixwindows.com/run-dism-command-windows-10/

Comment: There's an edit button for a reason and its a really good idea to use it as much as necessary, especially when adding things to your own post.